# AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12

Tags: java, android, audioflinger

I'm trying to play an audio Stream using audioTrack, so i have created audioTrack like this:

```
  public AudioTrack create() {
    if (mTrack != null) {
        if (mTrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            return mTrack;
        } else {
            mTrack.release();
            mTrack = null;
        }
    }

    mBuffSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(Settings.SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, Settings.SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, mBuffSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    if (mTrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
        mTrack.play();
        return mTrack;
    }
    return null;
}
```

when i finis
i call stop like this:

```
public void stop() {
    if (mTrack != null) {
        if (mTrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            mTrack.release();
            mTrack = null;
        }

    }

}
```

in some device, When i frequently create and stop, i get this:

AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12.

I searched this issue in StackOverflow many times, but all the answers talk about soundpool , and i have not used a soundpool

Any help would be greatly appreciated!(i'm a Chinese and my English is not good)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code..paste your code snippets directly

Comment: Thanks !but i dont know how to do this,  so how about this?

Comment: Yeah..better now..

Comment: Have you added permissions in your manifest?

Comment: witch permission i need to add? i'm not sure,but it runing nomally in other divece

Comment: It sounds like you have short sound clips and you are playing them many times quickly. The other answers talk about [`SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) with this error because that's what you should be using. The native resources behind `AudioTrack` are not released fast enough for your use case.

Comment: @Dave My Application is running in interphone , it can receive short or long audio stream frequently. once play finished, i call stop().

Comment: My suggestion would be to reuse a single `AudioTrack` instance for playback. Do not release and recreate the `AudioTrack`. Instead, call `flush`, `pause`, and `play` to make transitions from one source to another.

Comment: @Dave oh! This is really useful! I just do what you say! thank you very much bro!

Comment: @Zenan.Lai I hope so. If I have helped you devise a solution, I will post it as an answer. Please edit my answer with the working code.

Comment: @Dave OK,I will. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

to play the audio stream.